# How to use `strsplit` before every capital letter of a camel case?

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I want to use **`strsplit`** at a pattern *before* every capital letter and use a positive lookahead. However it also splits *after* every, and I'm confused about that. Is this regex incompatible with `strsplit`? Why is that so and what is to change?

```
strsplit('AaaBbbCcc', '(?=\\p{Lu})', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
strsplit('AaaBbbCcc', '(?=[A-Z])', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
strsplit('AaaBbbCcc', '(?=[ABC])', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "A"  "aa" "B"  "bb" "C"  "cc"
```

**Expected result:**

```
# [1] "Aaa" "Bbb" "Ccc"
```

In the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vxsOZB/1)  it actually looks fine.

Ideally it should split before every *camel case*, e.g. `Aa` and not `AA`; there's `\\p{Lt}` but this doesn't seem to work at all.

```
strsplit('AaaABbbBCcc', '(?=\\p{Lt})', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "AaaABbbBCcc"
```

**Expected result:**

```
# [1] "AaaA" "BbbB" "Ccc"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that by adding `(?!^)` you can obtained the desired result.

```
strsplit('AaaBbbCcc', "(?!^)(?=[A-Z])", perl=TRUE)
```

For the camel case we may do

```
strsplit('AaaABbbBCcc', '(?!^)(?=\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll})', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
strsplit('AaaABbbBCcc', '(?!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])', perl=TRUE)[[1]]  ## or
# [1] "AaaA" "BbbB" "Ccc"
```